# Program to watch a talk along with slides

Tags: gratis, video

I have the video and the slides (PDF) of a 1-hour talk. I'm looking for a program that would:

- display the video and the slides side-by-side as [videolectures.net](http://videolectures.net/nips2010_tenenbaum_hgm/) does: I don't want to have to manually scroll a PDF will watching the video. It should be able to take PDF as input for slides, and support the most common video formats. The video often shows the current slide, which permits synchronization with the PDF.

And if possible:

- work on Windows 7, but other Windows or Linux is OK too
- free
- option to speed up the watching speed (e.g. x1.25) is a plus

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Mozilla Popcorn](https://popcorn.webmaker.org) might be some use. It allows rich objects to be presented alongside video.

It looks like it may only work for web-video, so if you have the rights you might be able to upload to YouTube and mark as private?

Comment: Add a screenshot and I'll upvote… ;)