# Video and slides - side by side

Tags: video-editing, presentation

I'm trying to find a software for PC, Mac or Linux, which simultaneously plays a video on the left and a given Powerpoint/slides/group of pictures on the right. My goal is to create a video which shows complementary icons, texts, and slides about what the person at the left is talking about.

I've been told to learn using VLC to do that, or even start learning more complex video edit program because it's no easy task. What I'm trying to find is a software than can easily create such a presentation and has a simple interface for beginners like [PowToon](http://www.powtoon.com/) and [Animoto](https://animoto.com/).

Does such a tool/software exists?

Edit: A program like Mozilla Popcorn Maker allowing me to download my videos is EXACTLY what I am looking for.

Edit2: Presentz is, too, EXACTLY what I want. To show slides in one side and video in another.

Comment: A program like [Mozilla Popcorn Maker](https://popcorn.webmaker.org/) allowing me to download my videos is EXACTLY what I am looking for.

Comment: Related: [Program to watch a talk along with slides](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2099/903)

Comment: Nice link Franck, it does suggests Mozilla Popcorn Maker which is fantastic but I can't download the video and protect it from public view.

Comment: Just in case: You do know that you can embed video in Powerpoint presentations?